# C string doesn't iterate correctly in loop

Tags: c, arrays, arm, embedded, beagleboneblack

I am trying to print string through a UART0 from Beaglebone Black .The bootloader initializes UART0 and I just have to write characters. I have made a simple function

```
void uart_put(unsigned char c)
{
    while((UART0->LSR_r & 32) == 0);
    UART0->THR = c;     
}
```

From the startup code the following function is called I simply print character in this function.

```
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 7 
int c_entry(void)
{
unsigned char s_name[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = "Hello";
unsigned char a_name[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = {'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};
unsigned int a_int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = {9,8,7,6,5,4};
int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
      uart_put('0'+i);      /*print value of i*/
      uart_put(9);          /*print a tab*/
      uart_put(s_name[i]);  /*print char from string*/
      uart_put(9);          /*print a tab*/
      uart_put(a_name[i]);  /*print char from array*/
      uart_put(9);          /*print a tab*/
      uart_put('0'+a_int[i]);   /*print int from array*/
      uart_put('\n');
      uart_put('\r');
    }   
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The function is working fine as the array of characters and the integers is printed correctly, but the string is not printed as it should be. [image]

Comment: try "while (name[i] != '\0')"

Comment: @SaeidYazdani I doubt that it changes anything. BTW why doing this: `uart_put(name[5]);` since this one is the nul character?

Comment: Just for your information, and to nitpick a little, the newline sequence should be carriage return-newline. Not the other way around.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: this is same as the `while (name[i]>0)` i think i tried but it didn't work either

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude which proves that `\r` is not needed.

Comment: LF and CR are just added to make things more visible my question is related to the array being not printed, any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out the part where you print it manually before the loop, does anything change with the loop's output?

Comment: it prints somthing llike this `0       H
1       e
2       ▒
3       ▒
4       ▒ `

Comment: BTW I am using Linaro-gcc compiler for none eabi 4.7

Comment: What if you make the loop just `while (name[i]) { uart_put(name[i]); ++i; } uart_put('\r'); uart_put('\n');` (and still keep the prior stuff commented out)?

Comment: no still prints the same garbage

Comment: Is there any compiler or linker directive thats need to be defined for strings because i am working with bare metal may be i missed something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128473/discussion-between-uint32-and-arkku).

Comment: How exactly are you compiling, linking, and ultimately generating "download.bin"? I suspect the problem lies somewhere in that process, rather than in this code (which looks OK) - i.e. it could be something really subtle like the stack pointer overlapping the data so the initialisation of the local variable destroys the very thing it's copying. Another trick (if you don't have a JTAG debugger) would be to toggle one or more GPIOs at various points in the code to get an external indication of exactly whereabouts it's got stuck (e.g. spinning on the UART, off in some exception, etc.)

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/LFfEMXVH) is the make file may be I made some mistake here

Comment: @Notlikethat and others who may know how to help, **the linker script, startup code, etc. can be found in the chat.**

Comment: It appears `while((UART0->LSR_r & 32) == 0);` is not working as intended.    Try a large delay instead for debug.  Code may be failing for a number of reasons: mal-formed `UART0->LSR_r`, it is not `volatile`.  Further the problem could be at the receiving end not handling data received.  Or rarely slightly mis-matched baud.

Comment: @chux and others I have edited the question to explain the problem better the `UART0->LSR_r` is indeed `volatile` and since the loop prints the integer and char array this proves it but only problem is with string.

Comment: `unsigned char s_name[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = "Hello";` - remove the `{}`

Comment: @Mat well that is not a real problem I removed it

Comment: Can you compare `s_name[i] == a_name[i]` to see whether the difference can be confirmed before character printing?

Comment: I checked this condition but the condition doesn't satisfy, which means they are not one to one same

Comment: [They must be the same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) by definition of what string literal array initialization is, for a C-compliant compiler. That's why I think it's something hardware- or architecture-specific the compiler does not account for correctly.

Comment: Let me see your map file?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/bKyL2tZ9) is the map file

Comment: Since these are writeable strings, they are built on the stack, it is possible that the stack is off or the compiler noticed that they weren't being written to and did something weird.  What happens if you switch the order in which the variables are declared and what happens if you use different strings ("hello" for and {'w','o','r','l','d',} for the other )?

Comment: I wonder if the `unsigned char` is throwing the compiler off. What if it were declared as `char s_name[]`?

Comment: Just use `static` and `const`.  For instance, `static const unsigned char s_name[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = "Hello";`.  The rules for a string literal to an array and putting the thing on the stack are an issue.  The text look like a pointer/address or it could be a stack issue but then all of the would probably have issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the linker script, change:

```
. = 0x402F0400;
```

to:

```
. = 0x80000000;
```

Per the [memory map for the AM335X ARM processor](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_Boards), `0x402F0400` is the core SRAM while `0x8000000` is the DDR2 memory.  Per the screenshot of the TFTP boot output, you are loading your application at `0x80000000`, but your linker script is configured to reference the memory at `0x402F04000`.

Disassembling the raw binary file `download.bin` built using the original linker script yields:

```
% arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -b binary -marm download.bin
download.bin:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
    0:   e51fd000        ldr     sp, [pc, #-0]   ; 0x8
    4:   eb00000e        bl      0x44
    8:   402f1638        eormi   r1, pc, r8, lsr r6      ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
    c:   e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    [removed several lines of text]
    4c:   e24dd030        sub     sp, sp, #48     ; 0x30
    50:   e300262c        movw    r2, #1580       ; 0x62c
    54:   e344202f        movt    r2, #16431      ; 0x402f
    [remainder of dump removed]
```

The string is copied from memory into the local variable.  Note that the address for the string copy is `0x402f062c` (the `movw` and `movt` commands load the address into the register).  A quick scan of the omitted code does not show any other attempts to access memory.

I don't have access to a Beaglebone Black so I am unable to test this.  It does explain the observed behavior.  As the program is copying the string from uninitialized SRAM, there is no guarantee of what will be displayed.  As there is no other attempt to access memory within the program, this is the only issue.

Changing the linker script and rebuilding results in a slightly different `download.bin`.  A diff between the disassembled `download.bin` produced by the original linker script and my suggested change is:

```
10c10
<    8: 402f1638        eormi   r1, pc, r8, lsr r6      ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
---
>    8: 80001238        andhi   r1, r0, r8, lsr r2
28,29c28,29
<   50: e300262c        movw    r2, #1580       ; 0x62c
<   54: e344202f        movt    r2, #16431      ; 0x402f
---
>   50: e300222c        movw    r2, #556        ; 0x22c
>   54: e3482000        movt    r2, #32768      ; 0x8000
```

You can clearly see the new address reference for copying the string.  Unfortunately, I'm unsure what the other change is and if this change will cause any issues.

Just to verify the string is at 0x8000022c, we can use xxd to dump `download.bin`.  The output is:

```
% xxd download.bin
0000000: 00d0 1fe5 0e00 00eb 3816 2f40 04b0 2de5  ........8./@..-.
0000010: 00b0 8de2 14d0 4de2 0030 a0e1 0d30 4be5  ......M..0...0K.
[... omitted lots of lines ...]
0000220: 0500 53e3 cdff ffda feff ffea 4865 6c6c  ..S.........Hell
0000230: 6f00 0000                                o...
```

The string `Hello` is visible at `0x22c`.  When loaded at `0x80000000`, the address where the string is copied appears to be correct.

Comment: What a catch! Looking forward to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Ohh! silliest me I haven't thought about that thanks it works now XD

Comment: Congratulations, wow, that was a really tricky one! Impressive job everyone who participated!